# Finding closest number in a range

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I thought a problem which is as follows:

We have an array A of integers of size n, and we have test cases t and in every test cases we are given a number m and a range [s,e] i.e. we are given s and e and we have to find the closest number of m in the range of that array(A[s]-A[e]).

You may assume array indexed are from 1 to n.

For example:

```
  A = {5, 12, 9, 18, 19}
  m = 13
  s = 4 and e = 5
```

So the answer should be 18.

Constraints:

```
n<=10^5
t<=n
```

All I can thought is an O(n) solution for every test case, and I think a better solution exists.

Comment: If it is not sorted in any way, then you must access every value between A[s] and A[e], so O(n) it is.  Or rather O(e-s), I suppose.

Comment: @femtoRgon i know it, but by use of any data strucxture i think it is possible (just think but not sure).

Comment: Since you specified a maximum size bound (10^5), isn't the complexity O(1) - i.e. constant time?

Comment: @Chris this is a limit over the number of elements not over their value

Comment: @izomorphius if the numbers are supposed to be infinite precision integers, the complexity figures given so far are wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a rough sketch:
Create a [segment tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees) from the data. At each node, besides the usual data like left and right indices, you also store the numbers found in the sub-tree rooted at that node, stored in sorted order. You can achieve this when you construct the segment tree in bottom-up order. In the node just above the leaf, you store the two leaf values in sorted order. In an intermediate node, you keep the numbers in the left child, and right child, which you can merge together using standard merging. There are O(n) nodes in the tree, and keeping this data should take overall O(nlog(n)).

Once you have this tree, for every query, walk down the path till you reach the appropriate node(s) in the given range ([s, e]). As the tutorial shows, one or more different nodes would combine to form the given range. As the tree depth is O(log(n)), that is the time per query to reach these nodes. Each query should be O(log(n)). For all the nodes which lie completely inside the range, find the closest number using binary search in the sorted array stored in those nodes. Again, O(log(n)). Find the closest among all these, and that is the answer. Thus, you can answer each query in O(log(n)) time.

The tutorial I link to contains other data structures, such as sparse table, which are easier to implement, and should give O(sqrt(n)) per query. But I haven't thought much about this.

Comment: How do you decide what nodes to put into the tree? You can't add all possible left and right indices.

Comment: A segment tree is built on top of the array (each array element is a leaf) and every two leaf nodes are combined to give a next level node, and so on. You build the whole tree on the array as given in the tutorial. Then, searching for aggregate data in any given range requires traversing down atmost two branches in the tree.

Comment: Right, got it now. Me bad - I have worked with segment trees, but somehow could not envision how they fitted this problem.

Comment: @mayank i think your statement "there could be atmost 2 different nodes that would combine to form the given range" may not be correct, as the range could be formed by using more than two nodes for e.g say when total range is [1,8] and required range is [2,7] four nodes of segment tree are used. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Yes, on second thought, you are right. The number of destination nodes could be more than 2. But the traversal time would still be O(log(n)), though I was unable to rigorously prove it. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure no faster solution exists. A slight variation of your problem is:

*There is no array A, but each test case contains an unsorted array of numbers to search. (The array slice of A from s to e).*

In that case, there is clearly no better way than a linear search for each test case.

Now, in what way is your original problem more specific than the variation above? The only added information is that all the slices come from the same array. I don't think that this additional constraint can be used for an algorithmic speedup.

EDIT: I stand corrected. The segment tree data structure should work.

Comment: That isn't a slight variation, it's a major difference. When you have `A` in advance, you may be able to create a data structure during preprocessing that will allow faster searches.

Comment: My argument was that there does not exist such a data structure, but the segment tree idea in a different answer has me convinced otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

sort the array and do binary search . complexity : o(nlogn + logn *t )

Comment: will not work - you have the indices in the orginal array as part of the query. Read the statement again.